# About solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation :

$4xf'(x) = 2f''(0)x^2+f(2x)$

Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you know about $f$? If you know $f$ can be expressed as a power series, that would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

One family of solutions, by inspection (or if you prefer trying a likely polynomial given the homogeneous structure), is given by $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx^4$.

---

One could also consider a locally analytic solution $f= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n$. Then one finds

$$\sum ( 4n - 2^n)c_n x^n = 4 c_2 x^2$$

Now comparing coefficients we have a general analytic-at-the-origin solution as given above, since $4n-2^n\neq 0$ unless $n=4$ and at $n=2$ we also have agreement.

Comment: Thanks Sharkos for your answer. I'm searching if there are other forms of solutions. More precisely, I wonder if there is a general form for all solutions and how can we find it.

Comment: It's generally hard to solve functional equations like this where the function appears with multiple arguments in complete generality, and I have no immediate ideas about showing that all solutions are analytic vs finding non-analytic ones. Good luck!